# Sign-In Information for submit ios app to app store

Tags: ios

I want to publish an iOS app to the app store. After login Appstore connects, I fill all the information. But there is a part 'Sign-In Information' in prepare for submitting section, I do not understand. Which username and password have to give here, And what is the main work of this username and password. Help me please.

Comment: are you speeking of your apple developper account?

Comment: my first doubt is about which account is given here. Developer account or others like gmail.

Comment: Does your app have login feature? If yes, apple wants an account which can be used to login to your application and test the application. Not developer account.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR. yes, like phone number authentication.

Comment: Only phone number authentication? If so give a registered phone number in the email field and give a default otp like `1234` in password field

Comment: @RajeshKumarR, ok.. thanks a lot

Comment: @RajeshKumarR, Is it needed to any change in code? like default otp 1234 is not a valid otp.

Comment: You should set `1234` as default otp for specific phone number from backend

Answer (score 0):

The sign in information is for a demo account. If your app lets users login to their account then apple asks for a demo account so that they can login using the credentials you provide in `sign in information` and review the app.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is having `signin` or `login`. Then provide demo credential to apple reviewer team. So reviewer team can `log in` into the app by using this `credential` and review the app content and functionality. If your app doesn't contain such type of login functionality then keep it as blank.

That's it. Nothing else.